# Spring Boot app starts on Windows 10 but not on OS X (HS)

Tags: windows, eclipse, postgresql, spring-boot, macos-high-sierra

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to a postgresql-database. I am working on it on windows 10 (work) and macos (home). The code is shared via github. On win10 the app starts without any problems but when I update the code on macos and restart the app I often get the error `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

The one way I can remedy the issue is to include the H2 in-memory-db in `pom.xml`, start the app, remove it again and restart the Spring Boot app. But it doesn't always work.

My `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/john
spring.datasource.username=doe
```

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using Java JDK 10 in both environments with the Spring Tools suite in eclipse.

I have cleaned the project, updated maven right-clicking on the project -> Maven -> Update Project but without luck.

Comment: You might have java 10 compatibility problems.if it is easy for you to test with lower version, say 8, it will clear the doubts.

Comment: Hi. thank you for the suggestion. I changed it in the Build Path to 1.8 but unfortunately it did not make a difference.

Comment: It could be related to the eclipse IDE. I cloned the repo again and imported it into IntelliJ CE and it started without any issues.

Comment: can you add the full stack trace?